# Unix based OS: Coding Bug

Tags: c, unix

I am  trying to build an echo-like command which I named `code` at xv6. The problem is that if:

Input:

```
$code Hello World
```

Output:

```
user space:Hello user space:World
```

While the correct output should be:

```
user space: Hello World
```

Can somebody help me?

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int  i;

  if(argc <= 1){
    printf(1," %s user space:", argv[0]);
    exit();
  }

  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    printf(1, " print in user space:%s",argv[i]);
  }
  printf(1, "\n");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Correctly format your question, we may be able to answer.

Comment: `printf(1,...` what is that?

Comment: How do you not have `print in` anywhere in your output?

Comment: @Vladimir123 Hint: `Hello` and `World` are two *different* elements in `argv`.

Comment: I highly doubt that *that* code resulted in *that* output.

Comment: After you've fixed the `printf(1, …)` nonsense, you need to tell your shell to do what you want by using double quotes around the words you want treated as a single program argument: `code "Hello World"`.  The problem is not in your code — the "problem" is in the shell that you use to run your code.  The shell is doing what it is designed to do; you need to use it correctly by adding the double quotes as shown.

Comment: @Vladimir123 Please don't edit the question into a different one.

Answer (score 0):

program name is also passed as argument to your main function so you have three(as hello and world are considered separate arguments) arguments here .there is several issues in your code ,as you have two arguments first if statement will be false ,and you are not printing correctly in for loop ,following might be helpful :

```
int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int  i;
  printf("number of arguments : %d ",argc);
  //argv array index count from 0
  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    printf("argument number %d : %s",i,argv[i]); // issue in your code 
  }
  printf("\n");//issue in your code
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The text in your answer hes severe formatting errors.

Comment: This code is basically right, except that you probably want to start i at 1, to ignore the program name.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the write command so that you can output to stdout. Between each command line argument an additional space needs to be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int i;

  write(1, "user space: ", 12);

  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    size_t len = strlen(argv[i]);
    write(1, argv[i], len);
    write(1, " ", 1);
  }

  write(1, "\n", 1);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `write` is a non standard POSIX function. You should always use the standard `fwrite` method with `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part in your code is here:

```
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
 printf(1, " print in user space:%s",argv[i]);   //" print in user space:" is printed
                                                 //for each iteration
}
```

As others pointed out, you should rather do:

```
printf(" print in user space:\n");
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
   printf("%s",argv[i]);
}
```

That said, a few more remarks for you:

- I never seen a printf that takes an integer as first argument, I assume that the first parameter is not important/is a typo
- I am not an expert unix developer, but you can just use "return 0" (or "return 1") to quit your program. You will also be able to return an error code this way, as most unix programs do
- If you decide to use printf, be aware that it comes with a nasty security exploit [which can expose the caller's stack](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf) to a malicious user. Make sure your input is well formed or use a different function if possible

Comment: e.g. syslog log levels can use printf in this manner.  That said, I suspect the OP was confusing fprintf for printf, since the file descriptor for stdout is 1.